# Mirth connect consulta a postgresql

Tags: javascript, sql, interface

estoy tratando de armar un resultado  y tengo una consulta a postgresql dentro de otra, pero siempre me arroja que no existe una columna, tengo dentro de un STEP la creacion de la variable

```
var DBConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection(DBdriver,DBname,DBuser,DBpass);
```

y el codigo que me genera el resultado es:

```
OBRSQL = "select e.cod_fact, pe.autoriza as orden, e.nombre as descripcion, TO_CHAR(pe.fecha_toma::timestamptz, 'yyyymmddHH24MISS') as fecha_tomado,"+
            "pe.reg_exa, pe.examen "+
            "from public.paciente p "+
            "inner join public.paciente_examenes pe on (pe.paciente_cod = p.paciente_cod"+
            "   and pe.hora = p.hora"+
            "   and pe.fecha = p.fecha"+
            "   and pe.sede_codigo = p.sede_codigo"+
            "   and pe.historia = p.historia"+
            "   and pe.tipodcto_cod = p.tipodcto_cod"+
            "   and  pe.nit = p.nit)"+
            "inner join public.clientes c on (c.clte_codigo = p.clte_codigo)"+
            "inner join public.examenes e on (e.examen_cod = pe.examen)"+
            "where pe.paciente_cod = '"+msg['interf_paciente_cod'].toString()+"'"+
            "and pe.fecha = '"+msg['interf_fecha'].toString()+"'"+
            "and pe.sede_codigo = '"+msg['interf_sede_codigo'].toString()+"'"+
            "and pe.historia = '"+msg['interf_historia'].toString()+"'"+
            "and pe.tipodcto_cod = '"+msg['interf_tipodcto_cod'].toString()+"'"+
            "and pe.nit = '"+msg['interf_documento'].toString()+"'";

var cont = 1;
var ROBR = "";

try{
    var result = $('DBConn').executeCachedQuery(OBRSQL);
    while(result.next())
    {
        orden = result.getString("orden").trim();
        cups = result.getString("cod_fact").trim();
        descripcion = result.getString("descripcion").trim();
        fecha_tomado = result.getString("fecha_tomado").trim();
        examen = result.getString("examen").trim();
        reg_exa = result.getString("reg_exa").trim();
        
        ROBR = ROBR+'OBR|1|'+orden+'||'+cups+'^'+descripcion+'|||'+fecha_tomado+'||||||||||||||||||'+$('estado')+'||||||||||||||||||||||||||||\r\n';
        cont ++;
        // Inicio OBX
        OBXSQL = "Select distinct analito as analito_nombre, resultado, unidades as unidad, "+
                "(  tablav || ' ') || (((((( minimo) || ' ') || (CASE WHEN trim(intermedio) = 'SP' THEN '' ELSE  trim(intermedio) END  )) || ' ') || maximo) || ' ')  AS descripcionobx, "+
                "concat(TO_CHAR(fecha::date, 'yyyymmdd'), TO_CHAR(hora::time, 'HH24MISS')) as fechaval, "+
                "minimo as valorminimo, maximo as valormaximo, paciente_cod, fecha, nit, examen_cod, posiexa, analito_cod FROM resul_lab WHERE paciente_cod = '"+
                msg['interf_paciente_cod'].toString()+"' AND fecha = '"+msg['interf_fecha'].toString()+"' AND examen_cod = '"+examen+
                "' AND reg_exa = '"+reg_exa+"' AND resultado <> '_'";

        var contOBX = 1;
        var ROBX = "";
        try{
            var resultOBX = $('DBConn').executeCachedQuery(OBXSQL);
            while(resultOBX.next())
            {
                resultado = result.getString("resultado").trim();
                analito_cod = result.getString("analito_cod").trim();
                analito_nombre = result.getString("analito_nombre").trim();
                fechaval = result.getString("fechaval").trim();
                unidad = result.getString("unidad").trim();
                descripcionobx = result.getString("descripcionobx").trim();
                if(isNaN(valor)){
                    txtresult = "TX";
                }else{
                    txtresult = "NM";
                }
                ROBX = ROBX+'OBX|'+contOBX+'|'+txtresult+'|'+analito_cod+'^'+analito_nombre+'||'+resultado+'|'+unidad+'|'+descripcionobx+'||||'+$('estado')+
                      '|||'+fechaval+'|||||||||||||||||\r\n';
                contOBX ++;
            }
        }catch(e){
            logger.info('Exception 2: '+ e.message);
        }
        // Fin OBX
    }
}catch(e){
    logger.info('Exception 1: '+ e.message);
}

mensaje = $('encabezados')+ROBR+ROBX;

channelMap.put('mensaje', validate(mensaje, '', new Array()));
```

se que puede haber un error en la doble llamada de la conexión, pero no se como solucionarlo, si alguien tiene alguna luz por favor, o no se como mas podria iterar la respuesta. gracias
creo que la linea es var result = $('DBConn').executeCachedQuery(OBRSQL)